# How to check internal error in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table repeats  it's creat some type error inside row that cause 500 internal server error and stop cron job. 
If I remove some rows almost 30 it starts working 
Please suggest solution or how to find exact row causing error

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `APP_DEBU=true` on your `.env`, laravel logs all the errors on the `storage/logs`, so you can check there.